# In Apache Arrow, how can I update/delete data in vectors

Tags: apache-arrow

In Apache Arrow, how can I update/delete data base on conditions in a vector, what's the best practice of doing this?

Comment: Which language are you using Arrow in (Python, R, Java, ...?) and what version?

Comment: Thanks for replay, I'm using JAVA and arrow version is 4.0.0

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? And/or what you've tried? Vectors can be cast to the specific implementations and then they offer methods to get/set values.

Comment: For example, I have a int vector with value [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], what I want is: update 2 to 8, then  remove value 6, so vector will become [1, 8, 3,4,5,7]. Vector not limit to int, it can be varchar, timestamp, float, etc.

Comment: I would not think of vectors as vectors in the C++ sense or lists in the Java sense, in that deleting/editing/etc. is not necessarily cheap or easy (especially deletion). Instead, you'll probably allocate a new vector and copy values over, modifying or skipping values as appropriate.

Comment: For instance you might look at this implementation of a deduplicate operation which copies data over to a new vector: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/176988893e182ac418072ef8cd9a4bc598784d97/java/algorithm/src/test/java/org/apache/arrow/algorithm/deduplicate/TestDeduplicationUtils.java

Comment: @li.davidm Thanks for your answer, seems like this is the way it works